# Port confusion (breaks my .NET code)

Tags: .net, sockets, windows-7, ports

Using netstat i found this in my list

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9832         My-PC:9832          ESTABLISHED
```

My question is how is my local port outgoing AND CONNECTED to the same TCP port?

This is breaking my code because i am listening to port 9832. I am getting a permission error. I need to lose firefox and reopen all my tabs before this code will work. Another question i guess would be is there a range that should be used for listening and will not be use as an outgoing connection?

I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly valid to use the same port number for both outgoing connections and listening. If you are connecting to your own computer, then you'll get netstat output like you showed.

A TCP connection is identified by the 4-tuple (source-ip, source-port, dest-ip, dest-port), so there's nothing that says source-port cannot be the same as dest-port.

Perhaps you are binding to a particular port in your *client* code? Normally you only need to bind to a specific port for the *server* code.

Your issue about having to close Firefox is undoubtedly unrelated to this.

Comment: What not kosher, though, is having the same port at both ends of a *loopback* connection.  Then the 4-tuple would be the same in both directions.  Also, I don't think it's possible to establish a connection which has a loopback address on one side and a non-loopback on the other.

Comment: I thought it isnt valid to have a port for out and in especially if the IP Addr is the same. If a packet is sent from 127.0.0.1:123 to 127.0.0.1:123 how does it know if it was sent by the server or client? If i see a packet on the queue to 127.0.0.1:123 how do i know its the client or server receiving. That is so confusing.

Comment: My *client* code is some ajax. GM_xmlhttpRequest to be exact. I dont think it is possible to bind to a port. I have multiple clients with no problems. It just later when i get a problem. Maybe my sockets are still alive after i kill my process in VS. I am still confused.